# help with adding custom fields to invoice pdf

Tags: invoice

I want to add custom field to invoice pdf I am able to do it.

But problem is that my text gets overlapped with previous content. I think I need to increase rectangle with to do it but could not figure it out.

Ii just want to add text in the format :

```
Custiomer  Vat/ Tax number : ABD
```

below order date.

What I did to make it work:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php
```

changed this

```
$page->drawText(
    Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Date: ') . Mage::helper('core')->formatDate(
        $order->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), 'medium', false
    ),
    35,
    ($top -= 15),
    'UTF-8'
);
```

to

```
    $page->drawText(
        Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Date: ') . Mage::helper('core')->formatDate(
            $order->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), 'medium', false
        ),
        35,
        ($top -= 15),
        'UTF-8'
    );

$page->drawText(
            Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tax/Vat Number: ') .'ABC',
            35,
            ($top -= 15),
            'UTF-8'
        );
```

but my content gets cut pls help

Answer (score 1):

OK so first of all, do not override the core code. Make your own extension or at the very least put it in app/code/local.

For your cutting off problem, you copy/pasted the line without thinking about what you just copy pasted.

```
$page->drawText(
            Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tax/Vat Number: ') .'ABC',
            35,
            ($top -= 15),
            'UTF-8'
        );
```

1. The text
2. The X coordinate (starts at position 35 on the x-axis)
3. The Y coordinate (top value minus 15)
4. Character encoding (UTF-8)

So what you could try is playing around with your Y coordinate until you are satisfied. Or you could use one of the many invoice extensions http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/site-management/billing-invoicing.html